# WebStorm's Autocomplete not working for one exact file (treated as plain text)?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ide, webstorm

My WebStorm's autocomplete stopped working today.

I made a new component and wanted to call it `ProductArticleManager` as it's the most fitting name for it.

[image]

However, the Autocomplete for that single file just refuses to work. Looks like the IDE can't recognize it as a JS file.

I also made another folder called `NewComp` and made a component `NewComp.js` to check if it has anything to do with filename matching the folder name, but `NewComp.js` works fine.

Is there something wrong with this particular name?

What i already did after a little googling:

1. Restarted the IDE and computer, of course.
2. Checked that `Power Saving Mode` is off.
3. Tried `File => Invalidate Cache / Restart` option.
4. Right clicked on the root folder and set it as Resource Root.
5. Renaming the working `test.js` file to `ProductArticleManager.js` turned off the Autocomplete.
6. Moving the entire folder to another folder.
7. Deleting `ProductArticleManager` folder and re-creating it didn't work either.

I work in Ubuntu v20.04, WebStorm v2020.3.

Comment: Quick and dirty way: copy a working file and rename it. This should work I guess

Comment: test.js stopped working as soon as i renamed it to ProductArticleManager.js LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the file is treated as plain text.

Please check the registered patterns in **Settings | Editor | File types -> Text** and **Auto-detect file type by content** file types - can you see `ProductArticleManager.js`  there? Removing this pattern from the list should help

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When i visit Settings | Editor | File types -> Text i don't see `Auto-detect file type by content`. However, there's a tab called Ignored Files and Folders but my file isn't there either.

Comment: there is no **Auto-detect file type by content** in **Settings | Editor | File types | Text**, there are 2 separate file types -  **Settings | Editor | File types | Text** and **Settings | Editor | File types | Auto-detect file type by content**. You have to check registered patterns in both

Comment: Thank you! That one file was added to `Auto-detect file type by content`. Could you please elaborate on how i could have possibly added that one file there?

Comment: Looks like you have added this file via **File > New > File...** and didn't enter the extension first. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207062135-One-js-file-not-recognized-as-javascipt-others-ok?page=1#community_comment_360002575820 for details